# bash script to tar multiple domain folders

Tags: bash, backup, bash-scripting

## !/bin/bash

```
sitedir="$HOME/domains"
logs="$HOME/site_backups/log"

tbackups="$HOME/site_backups/today"
ybackups="$HOME/site_backups/yesterday"

echo "`date`"  > $logs/backups.log

for i in `ls`; do
    cd $sitedir/$i
    tar -czf $tbackups/$i".tar.gz" /public_html >> $logs/backups.log
done
exit 0
```

I want to backup every public_html folder inside a domain name ($home/domains/site.com/public_html) and make a tar in a $HOME/site_backups/today with the domain name. However, when i run my bash scrip i am getting errors:

```
test.sh: line 12: cd: /home/user/domains/log: No such file or directory
test.sh: line 12: cd: /home/user/domains/test.sh: No such file or directory
test.sh: line 12: cd: /home/user/domains/today: No such file or directory
test.sh: line 12: cd: /home/user/domains/yesterday: No such file or directory
```

Why it cd's to /home/user/domains/.. ? I have specified `$sitedir/$i` which means `/home/user/domains/domain.name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls` runs in whatever the current directory is.  From your results, it must have been `/home/user/domains/`.  If you want to work on the directories in $sitedir, change to that directory first:

```
cd "$sitedir"
for i in */ ; do
    ( cd "$i" && tar -czf $tbackups/${i%%/}".tar.gz" public_html >> $logs/backups.log ; )
done
```

By using `*/` in places of `ls`, the shell returns a list of directories, which seems to be what you want, rather than just any file.

Lastly, I put the processing of "$1" in parenthesis (a subshell) so that, when the processing is over, the script is back in "$sitedir" and ready for the next loop.

Comment: Thanks, now i got this error: tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar (child): /home/user/site_backups/today/domain.com/.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Why is there "/" after the domain name? It should be domain.com.tar.gz

Comment: Sorry about that: it is fixed now.  The expression `${i%%/}` removes the trailing slash from the directory name.

Comment: Thanks. i'm gonna test it right now. Btw, is exit 0 necessary? Could you help please, now this script TAR'ing folders even in site_backups directory.

Comment: `exit 0` is not needed unless whoever starts the script (is it a cronjob?) cares about the exit code.  `exit 0` signals success.  Without it, the script will exit with the exit code of the last `tar` command.

Comment: Yes, i'm gonna use it on a cronjob. Can you tell me why my directories from site_backups/ folder is also tar'ed? Shouldn't it TAR only $HOME/domains/ ?

Comment: @Heihachi The line `tar -czf $tbackups/${i%%/}".tar.gz" /public_html` is tarring `/public_html` which is an absolute path (starts with a slash).  It sounds like you wanted a relative path, as in `tar -czf $tbackups/${i%%/}".tar.gz" public_html`.  This will tar files from the `public_html` subdirectory of "$i".  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, i want to TAR only public_html directory. Can you please explain, why TAR'ing now the site_backups directory? It's not mentioned anywhere in the script :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12162/discussion-between-john1024-and-heihachi)